# FadeIn and fadeOut DIV border for 3 seconds only

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I keep a fadeIn and fadeOut active for 3 seconds and clear the effect?

html:

```
<div id="divid"></div>
```

css:

```
#divid{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#000;
 }
```

jQ:

```
var Interval;
function fadeInOut(divid){ 
   $('#'+divid).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
};

Interval = setInterval(fadeInOut(divId),600);
```

Comment: Can describe _"active for 3 seconds"_ ? Run `fadeInOut` three times , then stop ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I keep a fadeIn and fadeOut active for 3 seconds and clear the
>   effect?

If interpret Question correctly, try utilizing `.queue()` to call `.fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500)` three times sequentially , then stop; queue should be empty, or "clear the effect"

```js
$("#divid").queue("_fx", $.map(Array(3), function() {
  return function(next) {
    return $(this).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500, next);
  }
})).dequeue("_fx");
```

```css
#divid {
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#000;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="divid">abc</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here. First off, I don't think you need an interval here. Also, the second param for `fadeIn` is a callback. You can pass the `fadOut` method there. Finally, change the iteration to 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds)

```js
fadeInOut();

function fadeInOut() {
    $('#divid').fadeOut(3000, function() {
       $(this).fadeIn(3000);
    });
}
```

```css
#divid{
    border:1px solid;
    border-color:#000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="divid"></div>
```